# PHP Pass Array to function - Maintain default values if not set

Tags: php, arrays, function, default-value

I have a function that takes an "Options" argument array for setting flags for querying a database. It looks like this

```
function c_SQL($SQL='', $FIELDS=array(), $OPTIONS=array('SINGLEROW'=>false,'foo'=>false,'bar'=>false)) {

}
```

I am trying to maintain the default array keys if I do not set them in my function call:

```
$test = c_SQL($query,$fields,array('SINGLEROW'=>true));
```

This is generating an error inside the c_SQL function when we do checks against the array keys not specified (foo and bar).

Is there a way to maintain  'foo' and 'bar' if not specified and only change the keys only if passed into the function?

Comment: Have you tried using the `isset` function? If the result is false, you could always manually set the variable there.

Comment: That was what I was leaning towards doing if there was not a way to maintain the defaults.  We're just dealing with a lot of "potential" options being passed in and were trying to avoid checking each one

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could hold the defaults as a constant, and use [`array_merge`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php) to apply them to the user's input:

```
$DEFAULT_OPTIONS = array('SINGLEROW'=>false,'foo'=>false,'bar'=>false);
function c_SQL($sql='', $fields=array(), $options=array()) {
    $actual_options = array_merge($default_options, $options);
}
```

Comment: Excellent suggestion! I like this idea, as it will only overwrite the ones they specified.

Comment: @BryanZwicker This looks good but I think `$default_options` should go before `$options` in the call to `array_merge` because the second array overwrites the first array and you want your new options to override the defaults.

Comment: @Andrew I always mix the too up ;-( You are correct though - I fixed the answer accordingly. Thanks!

Comment: I noticed when I looked at the docs for array_merge().  I figured it was just a pseudo-code oversight :) Thanks again!

Comment: `$default_options` should be inside the scope of the function. It's useless anywhere else and there's a risk of a future conflict with another variable. See my solution.

Answer (score 5):

You can use `array_merge` inside the function to merge with a defaults array defined inside the function.

```
function c_SQL($SQL = '', $FIELDS=array(), $OPTIONS = array()) {
    $defaults =  array(
        'SINGLEROW' => false,
        'foo' => false,
        'bar' => false  
    );
    $OPTIONS = array_merge($defaults, $OPTIONS);
    return $OPTIONS;
}

#  array ( 'SINGLEROW' => false, 'foo' => false, 'bar' => false, )
var_export(c_SQL());

# array ( 'SINGLEROW' => true, 'foo' => false, 'bar' => false, )
var_export(c_SQL(array('SINGLEROW' => true)));
```

Answer (score 1):

Try assigning `$OPTIONS` as `null` or empty array and then check in function check if it is null or not, if its null then assign the array. Take a look at it here..

```
function c_SQL($SQL='', $FIELDS=array(), $OPTIONS=NULL) {
    if(empty($OPTIONS) {
        $OPTIONS=array('SINGLEROW'=>false,'foo'=>false,'bar'=>false)
    } else {
       $othervalues = array('SINGLEROW'=>false,'foo'=>false,'bar'=>false);
       $OPTIONS = array_merge($othervalues, $OPTIONS);
       //do something here
    }
}
```

Comment: If the passed array had only one or two of the three required options, it would still pass your condition.

Answer (score 1):

Create your default options inside the function body and then merge your new options with `array_merge`

```
function c_SQL($SQL='', $FIELDS=array(), $OPTIONS=array()) {
    $DEFAULTS = array('SINGLEROW'=>false,'foo'=>false,'bar'=>false);
    $OPTIONS = array_merge($DEFAULTS, $OPTIONS);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion! I like this method, it accomplishes exactly what I was trying to do. @Mureinik beat you to the punch by a few seconds, but +1